# How to format the phone number using TextInput in react - admin

Tags: validation, format, react-admin, textinput

```js
const phoneNumberFormat = (num) => {
    let newNum = num.replace(/[-]+/g, '');
    let x;
    if (newNum.length <= 3) {
        x = newNum;
    } else if (newNum.length > 3 && newNum.length <= 6) {
        x = newNum.slice(0, 3) + "-" + newNum.slice(3, 6)
    } else {
        x = newNum.slice(0, 3) + "-" + newNum.slice(3, 6) + "-" + newNum.slice(6, 10)
    }
    return x;
};
```

```js
const validatePhone = [required("Phone number is required"), phoneNumberFormat];
```

```js
<TextInput 
  className="location-input" 
  label="Cell phone" 
  source="phone" 
  validate={validatePhone} 
/>
```

if I enter a phone number it will be automatically format 123-456-7890 like this if you have any idea most welcome.

Now it only shows a validation message only, but I need to automatically format the phone number 123-456-7890

Comment: I think that you should not use the `validate` prop to format the phone number but the `format` and `parse` methods instead https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#common-input-props.

Comment: Thank U sir it's working now.

Answer (score -3):

```
<TextInput 
className="location-input"
parse={phoneNumberFormat}
label="Cell phone" 
source="phone" 
validate={validatePhone} 
/>
```